# What level prediction (node- or graph-level) is appropriate for my graph network problem?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I have experience in neural networks and just started exploring if graph NN is appropriate for my problem.

So, I have an undirected graph with nodes separated within a specified distance being connected. The only feature of a node is whether it is a city or not (1 or 0). The feature of an edge is the distance (as a vector, with 3 cartesian coordinates) between the nodes. My aim is to predict some new vector associated with ONLY the central node (may be we can think of this vector as pointing in the direction of the minimum node density from the central node). Generally, this vector depends on the features of the nodes and edges in some unknown, nonlinear fashion.

[image]

I feel this is not a node-level prediction problem since the other nodes does not have a feature of this kind (a vector). Also, this does not look like a graph-level prediction since the required vector is closely connected to a particular node in the graph structure. Can anyone please suggest if there is a way to study this problem using graph NN? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Better post this question on [DSStackExchange](https://datascience.stackexchange.com).

Comment: This does not sound to me like a graph problem at all. This is more like a particle problem, or a radial function minimization problem.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you're just trying to find a vector pointing from the central node (you either know which one is central, or calculate it) such that the direction is pointing directly away from the average node location? If that's not the case, please specify how do you quantify "node density" and what holds for a vector which points in the direction of "minimum node density".

Comment: @CaptainTrojan Thanks for your response. I know the centre node because this is the particle whose vector I am interested, and all the other nodes in the graph are within a cutoff distance (larger than the cutoff used to connect nodes by an edge) from the centre node. The problem is not really about the vector pointing toward some low "node density". I said that for simplification. In materials science parlance, I am interested in where the centre atom jumps given the position of neighboring atoms.

Comment: @AjayA Okay, good clarification. So what you're saying is that you don't really know where the central atom jumps, because it cannot be easily calculated from its and its surroundings' position, but have a lot of data of central atoms with surrounding atoms (within cutoff distance) and the observed jumping vectors of central atoms, and want to build a ML model which predicts those jumping vectors given a central atoms and its surroundings?

Comment: @CaptainTrojan Exactly. I have been using CNN with decent success but want to try graph NN. Do you have experience with this? I can PM you for more details if you think you can help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235837/discussion-between-captain-trojan-and-ajay-a).